# Setting ActionBar Elevation on pre-5.0 devices with AppCompat

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design, android-appcompat

I want to remove the shadow from the `ActionBar` and I read you do this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0)
```

However this didn't seem to work on Pre 5.0 devices. Is that a bug? I am not using the Toolbar. Just regular ActionBar from the library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using the ActionBar (not the Toolbar) you should be able to remove the shadow below using this style:

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Comment: How come it doesn't work in my case for Android 5.0 ? It's exactly the same theme I use and I've added this item... Also, how do I set it to the Toolbar (whether I use it with "setSupportActionBar" or not) ?

Comment: @android developer

On Lollipop, the action bar shadow is provided using the new elevation API. To remove it, either call getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0), or set the elevation attribute in your Action Bar style.
Source: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html